# Interface from string to use as generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface, azure-service-fabric

I'm using Service Fabric in Azure and set up a proxy to an actor like this:

```
var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<T>(actorId);
```

Where T must be specified as the interface of the actor I'm calling.

Let's say I have the name of the interface as a string:

```
var interfaceName = "IUserActor";
```

Is there a way to instatiate a generic type by this string name? And if there is, how do I call a method specified in given interface by it's string name?

All actor interfaces inherits from IActor which is a part of Service Fabric.

Now I understand that this is not recommended, the point is to be able to access the actor state for a given actor, from tests and administrative purposes. Speed is insignificant in this case, so any reflection approach will do.

So, a basic usage example, not using the dynamic interface name:

```
public async Task<string> AdminGetState(ActorId actorId, string interfaceName){
   var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IUserActor>(actorId);
   var state = await proxy.AdminGetStateJson();
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty or efficient, but you can do this using reflection...

```
public async Task<string> AdminGetState(ActorId actorId, string interfaceName){

   //Find the type information for "interfaceName".  (Assuming it's in the executing assembly)
   var interfaceType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(interfaceName);

   //Use reflection to get the Create<> method, and generify it with this type
   var createMethod = typeof(ActorProxy).GetMethod(nameof(ActorProxy.Create)).MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType);

   //Invoke the dynamically reflected method, passing null as the first argument because it's static
   object proxy = createMethod.Invoke(null,new object[] { actorId });

   //As per your comments, find the "AdminGetStateJson" method here.  You're REALLY trusting that it exists at this point.
   var adminGetStateMethod = interfaceType.GetMethod("AdminGetStateJson");

   Task<string> stateTask = (Task<string>)adminGetStateMethod.Invoke(proxy, null);

   var state = await stateTask;
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state);
}
```

Final edit: Is this definitely what you want to be doing though?  I would be very hesitant to put code like this out in the wild.

Comment: Thanks! But your code still assumes it's an IUserActor, how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: I've updated it to cast to IActor is that ok?  You said IUserActor inherits from IActor right? you can now pass in the name of any interface that inherits from IActor and it will work

Comment: It does, but I need to be able to call "AdminGetStateJson" since it is implemented separately in each interface. IActor is not modifiable. I'm guessing I could use something like GetMethod("AdminGetStateJson") and invoke it, but I'm not sure which type I should use it on?

Comment: Indeed, you can use it on the type you resolve there (the variable "interfaceType" in my answer).  You would do interfaceType.GetMethod("AdminGetStateJson").    I'm not sure how it would play with async and await though.  Never tried that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to find the "AdminGetStateJson" method with reflection too.

Comment: I had to do some modifications, but it's actually working! Thanks a lot, much appreciated. Here is the final code if anyone's interested:
http://pastebin.com/CVKTGwEx

Comment: Why do you sound so surprsied that it's working?! :-P haha! glad you got it sorted